# replace string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. I want to look at one column and if any of the strings in the column contain @, I want to replace them with another string. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A dataframe in pandas is composed of columns which are series - [Panda docs link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

I'm going to use regex, because it's useful and everyone needs practice, myself included! [Panda docs for text manipulation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/text.html)

Note the str.replace. The [regex](https://docs.pyth%5Con.org/2/library/re.html) string you want is this (it worked for me): '.*@+.*' which says "any character (.) zero or more times (*), followed by an @ 1 or more times (+) followed by any character (.) zero or more times (*)

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace('.*@+.*', 'replacement')
```

Should work, where 'replacement' is whatever string you want to put in.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you called your dataframe `df`, you can do:

```
pd.DataFrame(map(lambda col: map(lambda x: 'anotherString' if '@' in x else x, df[col]), df.columns)).transpose()
```

Comment: If you're interested in a sublist of specific columns, just put them instead of df.columns

Comment: This replaces the @ value with the String I input, Im looking to replace the entire string with a new value if the current string contains @ sorry if I didnt specify

Comment: OK, I modified the answer accordingly

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion:

```
df['col'] = ['new string' if '@' in x else x for x in df['col']]
```

not sure which is faster.