# Removing contents within brackets in string

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to remove the brackets and contents withing the brackets from a string.
I tried following code:

```
a['Street Name'].str.replace('\(.*)','')
```

But it is not working. Can anybody please tell me what is wrong with this statement?

Comment: When you say 'not working', what do you mean? What's the contents of `a['Street Name']`? What result do you get? What result do you expect?

Comment: need `a['Street Name'] = a['Street Name'].str.replace(r'\([^)]*\)','')`

Comment: [A quick search and you could find the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702338/replace-string-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @Maroun Maroun contents of a['Street Name'] is "Dharwad (Hubballi-Dharwad avali Nagar)". I want the output as "Dharwad"

Comment: @bigblind the contents of a['Street Name'] is "Dharwad (Hubballi-Dharwad Avali Nagara). I want the output to be "Dharwad"

Comment: thank you very much for the help folks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re

s = "I want to remove all words in brackets( like (this) and ((this)) and ((even) this))."

while True:
    s_new = re.sub(r'\([^\(]*?\)', r'', s)
    if s_new == s:
        break
    s = s_new

print(s_new) # I want to remove all words in brackets.
```

Comment: No brackets will remove everything using this code